# How to convert automatically list of objects to JSONArray with Gson library in java?

Tags: java, json, gson

Lets say I have following list of custom object: `ArrayList<GroupItem>` where `GroupItem` is some class that has `int` and `String` variables.

I tried so far `Gson` library but it's not exactly what I want.

```
ArrayList<GroupItem> groupsList = /* ... */
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonElement element = gson.toJsonTree(groupsList, new TypeToken<ArrayList<GroupItem>>() {}.getType());

JsonArray jsonArray = element.getAsJsonArray();
```

My goal is to get `JSONArray` (org.Json.JSONArray) somehow. Any ideas?

**[EDIT]**

My project is Android with Cordova that has API based on `org.Json.JSONArray`

ANd I thought to write some generic way to convert instances to `JSONArray` / `JSONObject`

Thanks,

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples

Comment: I knew it was cordova! I did this at work last week. You do not need gson.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This way is worked for me:

Convert all list to String.

```
String element = gson.toJson(
                    groupsList,
           new TypeToken<ArrayList<GroupItem>>() {}.getType());
```

Create `JSONArray` from String:

```
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray(element);
```

Comment: Accepted answer returns an array of nulls, this works

Answer (score 7):

The `org.json` based classes included in Android don't have any features related to converting Java POJOs to/from JSON.

If you have a list of some class (`List<GroupItem>`) and you absolutely need to convert that to a `org.json.JSONArray` you have two choices:

A) Use Gson or Jackson to convert to JSON, then parse that JSON into a `JSONArray`:

```
List<GroupItem> list = ...
String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
```

B) Write code to create the `JSONArray` and the `JSONObject`s it will contain from your Java objects:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
for (GroupItem gi : list)
{
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("fieldName", gi.fieldName);
    obj.put("fieldName2", gi.fieldName2);
    array.put(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to use GSON to convert to an org.json class? Nor do you need to write any custom code to get a JSONArray. The [org.json api](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html) provides a way to do it.

```
  LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
  list.add("foo");
  list.add(new Integer(100));
  list.add(new Double(1000.21));
  list.add(new Boolean(true));
  list.add(null);
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(list);
  System.out.print(jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Jackson for JSON to Object or Object to JSON

See the next link [Jackson examples](http://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial)

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
objectMapper.writeValue(stringWriter, groupsList );
System.out.println("groupsList JSON is\n"+stringWrite);
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need gson. There's a [constructor](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.util.Collection%29) that takes a collection, so just:

```
ArrayList<GroupItem> groupsList =... ;
JSONArray JSONArray = new JSONArray(groupsList);
```

Comment: You don't need generics on the List.

Comment: i got proper list length but with nulls inside. see my answer

Comment: some time its throwing stack overflow exception for the same.

Comment: @Ranjitsinh you're not going to get any help posting a little hint of a problem you're having. You need to ask a full question.

Comment: @weston  I have not any problem but whenever I am using List<CustomObj> to json array I am getting stackoverflow exception so I am passing object with different way.

Comment: It may not be a problem for you now, but it was a problem right?! and you got around it. That's a useful question too. "This was what I was experiencing, then I did this and got around it, but what was wrong with the original version?"

Comment: You could provide an answer of your own to this question, saying what you did instead. But there's no point putting a tiny comment out of context like that on here, because you're saying "this is wrong/bad, don't use it" and you're not saying what to do instead.

Comment: @Ranjitsinh You're basically saying this is a bad answer when I bet you anything you like that it's something you're doing wrong.

Comment: @weston i decided to move accepted answer to mine because of high rate and comment. Sorry

Comment: @snaggs no worries